# iptables : reject connection to port if IP address IS NOT 1.1.1.1

Tags: iptables

Currently what i have is this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

but what i want is a single line like this:  ( more logical )

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -s ! 1.1.1.1 -j DROP
```

but this above line does not work due to this error:

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: Using intrapositioned negation (`--option ! this`) is deprecated in favor of extrapositioned (`! --option this`).
```

Answer (score 3):

As your error message says, just try :

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 ! -s 1.1.1.1 -j DROP
```

Place the `!` before the `-s` flag.